# Rundeck EC2 plugin provision instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, rundeck

I installed:

```
 - rundeck - 2.10.2 
 - rundeck-ec2-nodes-plugin - 1.5.5
```

I connected my jobs with existing aws EC2 instances on my account and it works great.

I search a lot but i cannot find answer for my question:

Can i use rundeck to provision EC2 instance as a node and then execute job on it and ofcourse after job is finish terminate this EC2 instance automatically??

Answer (score 0):

For now you can just wrap the aws cli to create a new EC2 instances (for example using a custom script plugin).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-launch.html#launching-instances

If you want to create a new instance and runs some process on that instances on the same workflow, probably you need to call the "Refresh Project Nodes" steps to refresh the node resources.

Luis